# Not able to register for push in iOS

Tags: push, ios9

For some reason, in ios9, in the methods:BOOL ParseCheckPermissionForRemoteNotifications(void) and void ParseRegisterForRemoteNotifications(BlockBoolAction completion), I cannot reach the parse servers. In ios8, it works perfectly fine. I've tried remaking the SSL certificate and provisioning profile and adding exceptions to NSapptransportsecurity. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?